# Training with Global Batch Size on a TPU (tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow2.0, tpu, batchsize

I've recently started a neural network project on Google Colab, and I discovered that I could use a TPU. I've been researching about how to use it and I discovered tensorflow's `TPUStrategy` (I'm using tensorflow 2.2.0), and have been able to successfully define the model and run a train step on the TPU.

However, I'm not exactly sure what that means. It might be that I didn't read Google's TPU guide thoroughly enough, but I mean I don't know what exactly happens during a train step.

The guide asks you to define a `GLOBAL_BATCH_SIZE`, and the batch size that each TPU core takes is given by `per_replica_batch_size = GLOBAL_BATCH_SIZE / strategy.num_replicas_in_sync`, which means that the batch size per TPU is less than the batch size you start with. On Colab, `strategy.num_replicas_in_sync = 8`, which means if I start with a `GLOBAL_BATCH_SIZE` of 64, the `per_replica_batch_size` is 8.

Now, what I don't understand is whether, when I compute a train step, the optimizer computes 8 different steps on batches of size `per_replica_batch_size`, updating the weights of the model 8 different times, or it just parallelizes computation of the train step this way and in the end computes only 1 optimizer step on a batch of size `GLOBAL_BATCH_SIZE`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question and is more related to **`Distribution Strategy`**.

After going through this [Tensorflow Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/custom_training#define_the_loss_function),[TPU Strategy Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training#tpustrategy) and this explanation of [Synchronous and Asynchronous Training](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training#types_of_strategies),

I can say that

```
> the optimizer computes 8 different steps on batches of size
> per_replica_batch_size, updating the weights of the model 8 different
> times
```

The below explanation from [Tensorflow Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/custom_training#define_the_loss_function) should clarify that:

```
> So, how should the loss be calculated when using a
> tf.distribute.Strategy?
> 
> For an example, let's say you have 4 GPU's and a batch size of 64. One
> batch of input is distributed across the replicas (4 GPUs), each
> replica getting an input of size 16.
> 
> The model on each replica does a forward pass with its respective
> input and calculates the loss. Now, instead of dividing the loss by
> the number of examples in its respective input (BATCH_SIZE_PER_REPLICA
> = 16), the loss should be divided by the GLOBAL_BATCH_SIZE (64).
```

Providing the explanation from other links as well below (just in case they don't work in future):

[TPU Strategy documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training#tpustrategy) states:

```
> In terms of distributed training architecture, `TPUStrategy` is the
> same `MirroredStrategy` - it implements `synchronous` distributed
> training. `TPUs` provide their own implementation of efficient
> `all-reduce` and other collective operations across multiple `TPU`
> cores, which are used in `TPUStrategy`.
```

The explanation of [Synchronous and Asynchronous Training](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training#types_of_strategies) is shown below:

```
> `Synchronous vs asynchronous training`: These are two common ways of
> `distributing training` with `data parallelism`. In `sync training`, all
> `workers` train over different slices of input data in `sync`, and
> **`aggregating gradients`** at each step. In `async` training, all workers are
> independently training over the input data and updating variables
> `asynchronously`. Typically sync training is supported via all-reduce
> and `async` through parameter server architecture.
```

You can also go through this [MPI Tutorial](https://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-reduce-and-allreduce/) to understand the concept of All_Reduce in detail.

The screenshot below shows how All_Reduce works:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am doing in sync training, so the gradients are aggregated by All_Reduce, right? But doesn't that mean it's just updating the weights once with the summed gradients, rather than 8 times? Or does it mean the weights are updated 8 times with the same gradients?

Comment: For the example of having 8 replicas and per_replica_batch_size = 8, I believe that the optimizer should update the weights only 1 time and just after the gradients from all replicas have been received. If it updated the weights 8 times, then there will be different results when compared with single device training (1 replica).

Answer (score 0):

If you has few card to use, use GLOBAL_BATCH_SIZE parallel strategy can break the GPU memory boundaries and still use larger batch sizes.

It will computes 8 times when calculate grad of each mini-batch(`per_replica_batch_size`), but update the model variables only one time after the global batch gradients are calculated.

[image]

Reference: [How to Break GPU Memory Boundaries Even with Large Batch Sizes](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-break-gpu-memory-boundaries-even-with-large-batch-sizes-7a9c27a400ce)